# Does the routine flown by the Thunderbirds in the F-16 feature true sustained knife-edge flight?

Tags: military, flight-controls, aircraft-physics, sideslip, airshow

Does any aerobatic routine flown by the USAF Thunderbirds in the F-16 feature true sustained knife-edge flight?

By "true sustained knife edge flight" we mean that the aircraft is maintaining a constant altitude in a 90-degree bank.  It is not merely flying a ballistic trajectory, which would be manifested by the vertical speed steadily becoming less positive or more negative.

If so, is any special modification to the flight control system required to make this possible?

This question is motivated by the related ASE answer https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/35986/34686 .

Comment: That's an interesting question.  Since the plane can fly straight up, there will be SOME angle between vertical and horizontal where fuselage lift + thrust can support the machine while moving laterally, maybe 20, or 30 or 40 degrees.  The question becomes is there enough tail power in the rudder to maintain that body AOA, whatever it is.   I've never seen any team do that sort of maneuver, and I suspect that nobody has ever tried it, so the answer is probably nobody knows.

Comment: @JohnK -- Maybe a logical extension of your point, is that "knife edge" flight is easier when climbing?  (The question is aimed at a true horizontal flight path.)

Comment: Climbing would just require more power.  Note that just about any horizontal flight path has an engine thrust component.  The thrust line just has to be above horizontal.  A regular plane in slow flight is getting maybe 5% of its lift from the vertical component of the thrust line.  A 180 HP Pitts S1 flying knife edge in level flight at a 30 deg angle is getting maybe 2/3rds of its lift from the fuselage and the rest from the prop (800lbs angled 30 deg is about a 400 lb vertical component).